# sort Csv using date column (dd/mm/yyyy) java

Tags: java, date, csv

i have csv as input with 2 columns and want to sort data on basis of date column (dd/mm/yyyy). below code sort the date correctly but i want the related value with that date... output of this code is like

```
 02/05/2012
 09/11/2012
 10/11/2012
```

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Date value = null;
    String reader ="";
    String[] input = null ;
    Date date;
    List<Date> dateList = new ArrayList<Date>();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    File file = new File("data.csv");

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while((reader = br.readLine())!=null){              
            input = reader.split(",");              
             date = df.parse(input[0]);
             dateList.add(date);
        }

        Collections.sort(dateList, new Comparator<Date>() {
             public int compare(Date o1, Date o2){
                 return o1.compareTo(o2);
             }
        });

         for(Date x : dateList){
             System.out.println(df.format(x));               
         }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fi) {
        fi.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(ParseException pe){
        pe.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

Comment: There are two comparators in your code and both not relavent to your requirement and your sample doenst look like csv

Comment: Down voters to add appropriate comment before down voting

Comment: What is the input data? Can you give an example?

Comment: data is in csv file containing 2 columns date and value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's easiest to use an object to represent each row of your csv.  Then, sort those rows.  For extra points, have `DateRow` implement Comparable.

The relevant part inside your try block:

```
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
     while((reader = br.readLine()) != null) {
         input = reader.split(",");
         DateRow row = new DateRow(
           input,
           df.parse(input[0])
         );
         dateList.add(row);
     }

     Collections.sort(dateList, new Comparator<DateRow>() {
          public int compare(DateRow o1, DateRow o2){
              return o1.getKey().compareTo(o2.getKey());
          }
     });

     for (DateRow row: dateList) {
         System.out.println(row.getData()[0] + "\t" + row.getData()[1]);
     }
```

The DateRow class (keep it static if you want it to be an internal class of whatever your main method is in):

```
private static class DateRow {

    private Date key;
    private String[] rowData;

    public DateRow(String[] rowData, Date key) {
      this.rowData = rowData;
      this.key = key;
    }

    public String[] getData() {
      return this.rowData;
    }

    public Date getKey() {
      return this.key;
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried ur solution ...there is an error in adding data row to the dateList .... how can i resolve this  @Eric Hughes

Comment: You are probably still declaring dateList as `ArrayList<Date>` ... make it an `ArrayList<DateRow>`.  In the future, if you have an exception, could you please give more data about the exception, and the line it occurs on?  Otherwise we just have to guess.